# Is "goose bumps" one or two words?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference, orthography

I would like others to explain this to me.
Which is correct?

1. goosebumps
2. goose bumps

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners. Have you tried looking up either spelling in a dictionary?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=goose+bumps%2Cgoosebumps&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgoose%20bumps%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgoosebumps%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write either as goose bumps (two words) or as goosebumps (single word).

However, the former is more common than the latter.

Comment: You can also write "goose-bumps". They are widely called "goose pimples" in the UK, with or without a hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  Both can be valid, but the typical expression is one word:

> **[goosebumps](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/goosebumps)** (n): A state of the skin caused by cold, fear, or excitement, in which small bumps appear on the surface as the hairs become erect; goose pimples.

You can write it as two words and it will be understood; however you might also mean literal "bumps" somehow made of "geese".  Or, on a humorous note: One modern use of "bump" is the action of touching fists together (also called a "fist bump").

[image]

Ergo, "goose bumps":

[image]

Side note:  Other terms for "goosebumps":

> **horripilation** (from the Latin *horrēre*, "to bristle or shiver" or "to be dreadful or terrible," and Latin *pilus*, "hair.")
>
> **piloerection** (from the same *pilus* plus erection, thus "standing hair.")
>
> **cutis anserina** (used in medical texts, *cutis* is Latin for "skin", and *anserinus* for "goose", so literally "goose skin")
>
> **goose pimples**
>
> **goose flesh**

[More information](https://www.copyediting.com/words-to-make-your-hair-stand-on-end/)